# Interpolating discrete data Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spatial-interpolation

I have the data set in relation **z=f(x,y)** where x and y are coordinate points and z are the values with respect to these points.I need to get the z values between the spaces from x and y values. I have tried by doing the interpolation, and still it gives me the almost same results. So, my question is how to get the overall 'z' distribution on the 'xy' surface. Thank you

```
 [X,Y] = ndgrid(linspace(0,100,506),linspace(-85,85,2001));
     Z = griddata(x(:),y(:),z(:),X,Y,'linear');
```

[image]

Comment: What you've done looks reasonable, so what isn't working? Is the plot showing the input or the output?

Comment: Impossible to answer this question without more information.

Comment: @Justin The plot showing the input i.e before interpolating. After interpolating though the space were filled up, the values were NaN at some points.

Comment: Like AnonSubmitter85 said, there's just not enough information here to answer your question. You need to build a small example that demonstrates the problem and then post it... [mcve]